# О вёрстке длинных сносок

Tags: сноски

Кто сталкивался? Можно ли для удобства восприятия читателем и из соображений здравомыслия оставить кегль сноски таким же, как у основного текста, если многие сноски занимают по нескольку листов? Нет ли строгого запрета?

P.S. Предложения о создании концевой сноски и прочих альтернативах не интересуют.

Comment: Вспоминаю как давненько читал "Войну и Мир", где сноски порой на несколько страниц (перевод французского письма в начале I  тома). Там шрифт был примерно такой же, но набран курсивом. Можно взять в библиотеке несколько первых томов этого произведения и посмотреть как там реализовано.

Comment: @МаркИз Попробую. Спасибо. Вариант с курсивом точно не использую. На мой взгляд, будет довольно неприятно читать 12 листов курсива, ну, как, впрочем, и мелкого кегля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Традиция — уж точно следствие здравомыслия. Читатель должен с первого взгляда улавливать назначение поля и элемента набора на странице. Инновация должна быть крайней неизбежностью, и на практике не существует бескомпромисного решения в пользу предагаемой здесь меры уравнивания.

Решение может состоять (комплексно) в редактуре с целью переноса части сносимого материала в Примечания и поиска мер заметного, но минимального его отличия, возможно в размерности, цветности шрифта или фона.

Запрета на превышение площади под сноски нет, как и на использование одного кегля. Надо понимать, что такой необычный приём будет относить текст в разряд упрощённых или специфичных.

Comment: "Необычным приёмом" Вы называете одинаковый кегль или крупную сноску?

Comment: Вы полагаете, другая гарнитура шрифта сноски способна выступить альтернативой уменьшенному кеглю?

Comment: Я говорил о компромиссном, комплексном решении. О другой гарнитуре? Врядли с одной — на другую... Толщина иная может быть.

Comment: Кстати, да. Рациональное решение. На нём, наверное, и остановлюсь. Спасибо)